# Condition ? : operator in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have a problem with the `?:` operator, so I tried the `if-else` block and everything works fine. But when using the *other* operator, it just stops working.

```
using System;

namespace firstGame
{
    class Program 
    {
        public string playerName;
        public int playerScore;
        public int gameNumber;
        public int playerGuess;

        public void GameStart()
        {
            string r;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my first game");
            Console.Write("please enter your gamer name : ");

            this.playerName= Console.ReadLine();

            do
            {    
                this.gameNumber = Convert.ToInt16(new Random().Next(0,10));
                this.playerScore = 1;

                if (this.playerScore == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess the hidden number between (1-10)");

                    do
                    {
                        Console.Write("guess number {0} :: ", this.playerScore);
                        string num = Console.ReadLine();

                        int.TryParse(num, out _) ? this.playerGuess=Convert.ToInt16(num) : Console.WriteLine("Are you sure it is a number !!?") ;
                        this.playerScore++;
                    } while (this.playerGuess != this.gameNumber);

                    Console.WriteLine("BINGO {0} is the correct number", this.gameNumber);
                    Console.Write("would you like a new lvl ? (Y/N) :: ");  r=Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else 
                { 
                    this.playerScore = 0; 
                    break; 
                }
            } while (r=="Y");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().GameStart();
        }
    }
}
```

I made a mistake *somewhere*, but *where* and *how* is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `cond ? exp1 : exp2` the `exp1` and `exp2` must have the same type.

A ternary expression is not appropriate in your case because `Console.WriteLine` returns void but the assignment expression is an `int`.

Use the traditional *if-else* instead.

#### To fix

```
// ERROR: This doesn't compile
int.TryParse(num, out _) ? this.playerGuess=Convert.ToInt16(num) : Console.WriteLine("ar you sure it is a number !!?") ;
```

should become

```
if (int.TryParse(num, out _)) {
    this.playerGuess = Convert.ToInt16(num)
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("ar you sure it is a number !!?");
}
```

#### Bonus tip:

You probably actually want this:

```
if (int.TryParse(num, out int val)) {
    this.playerGuess = val;
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure it is a number?");
}
```

Comment: Bonus tip, they probably actually want `while(!int.TryParse(num, out playerGuess)) {Console.Write("are you sure it is a number?");mum=Console.Readline();}`

Comment: (Double bonus tip, writing an Ask method that does the write/read, then an AskInt method that uses it and insists on a number before it returns, usually cleans up those programming 101 apps quite a lot!)

Answer (score 0):

`?:` is not an *if then else*

[**The conditional operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

> The conditional operator ?:, also known as the ternary conditional
>   operator, evaluates a Boolean expression and returns the result of one
>   of the two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean expression
>   evaluates to true or false

Moreover, `Console.WriteLine` does not return a result, it's a void method that has side effects. So it cannot be used with an operator, full stop.

In short, just use an *if then else*.